# How to restrict Android Google autocomplete API to only get Train Stations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Although there are many answers on how to restrict the API to only a specific country, couldn't find anything regarding restricting it to the train stations. Please help me out on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not supported in the API at the moment.

I can see a feature request to enable this feature in Places API web service:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

I would suggest filing the same feature request for Places API for Android autocomplete.

You can also see similar feature requests for PlacePickers in Android and iOS:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826944

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830469