# How to filter out only Train Stations in Google Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to use Google Places AutoComplete API in my app, but I want to filter the results to Train Stations only rather than the complete Address. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not supported in the API at the moment.

I can see a feature request to enable this feature in Places API web service:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

I would suggest filing the same feature request for Places API for Android autocomplete.

You can also see similar feature requests for PlacePickers in Android and iOS:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826944

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830469

Possible Duplicate - [How to restrict Android Google autocomplete API to only get Train Stations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292779/how-to-restrict-android-google-autocomplete-api-to-only-get-train-stations)

Comment: ok, I am thinking to use here maps API to do this job, let's see. Anyway Thanks for your help.